# facebook graphs api - How to access reviews from public page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've seen quite a few solutions regarding accessing one's own reviews via the facebook graph api. However, my question was whether or not it was possible to access other reviews.

I basically want to access reviews for public businesses. Seeing as these reviews appear publicly on facebook, I figured this would be an easy task. However, I'm currently unable to find a way to do it: it asks for a page access token, which AFAIK only allows one access to their own page data.

Am I wrong here? Can I do what I plan to, or is it impossible as I am starting to believe it is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you need a page token, and yes, that means you can not get that data for pages that you don’t have admin access to. Just because something is public on facebook.com, does not mean it has to be publicly available via API as well.

Comment: it IS an easy task, but...well, see tobis answer and cbroes comment ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a Page Access Token to request the

```
/{page_id}/ratings
```

endpoint. It's all in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/ratings

> A page access token is required to retrieve this data.

Comment: Yea, I saw that section. I was just confirming that this applied to public information as well. That's a shame, but not entirely surprising. Thanks.